# Нужен слайдер с fade-эффектом и скроллом

Tags: jquery, slider

Всем привет!
Нужен слайдер с fade-эффектом (как [здесь](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/animate.html)) и скроллом (как [здесь](http://darsa.in/sly/examples/horizontal.html)). Может быть кто-то видел?

Нужен слайдер с обеими этими опциями одновременно. Sly имеет скроллбар, который мне нужен, но я не знаю, как у него включить fade-эффект. У Owl наоборот есть возможность включить fade-эффект, но нет скролла.

Comment: а эти скачать религия не позволяет? Или поставьте вопрос по другому или вы просто спамер.

Comment: Я хочу сказать, что мне нужен слайдер с обеими этими опциями одновременно. Sly имеет скроллбар, который мне нужен, но я не знаю, как у него включить fade-эффект. У Owl наоборот есть возможность включить fade-эффект, но нет скролла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Долго переваривал чего вы хотите, но так до конца и не понял. Смотрите [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/rq6bv53r/) с использованием jQuery UI Slider.

**HTML**

```
<div class="slides">    
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/&text=1" alt="" />        
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/&text=2" alt="" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/&text=3" alt="" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/&text=4" alt="" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/&text=5" alt="" />
</div>
<div id="slide_wrap">
    <div id='slider'></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var slideBox = $('.slides'),
    imgs = $('img', slideBox),
    len = imgs.length;

imgs.each(function(i, el){
    $(el).attr('data-indx', i + 1);
}).eq(0).appendTo(slideBox);

function rotateImg(n){
    imgs.finish();
    $('[data-indx=' + n + ']', slideBox)
        .hide()
        .appendTo(slideBox)
        .fadeIn(300);
    return false;
}

$('#slider').slider({
    min: 1,
    max: len,
    range: 'min',
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        rotateImg(ui.value);
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! То, что надо. Неужели так невнятно объяснил?..

Comment: @Beef, дело не во внятности объяснений, а их разной трактовке.

Answer (score 0):

[Вот этот](http://bxslider.com/) может подойдет?

Comment: Посмотрел все демки там - не увидел скроллбара. Нужен такой скроллбар, чтобы был ползунок, за который можно тянуть. Вот здесь (http://darsa.in/sly/examples/horizontal.html) смотрите у всех слайдеров такой сверху есть.